# Select fields from differents rows

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table Test

```
id value type 
1   100  prime
1   200  13 month 
2   120  prime
2   300  13 month
```

How can I get the following result

```
id valuePrime typePrime valueMonth typeMonth
1   100        prime      200      13 month
2   120        prime      300      13 month
```

Comment: If you have control over the schema, I would design it so there is a parent/child relationship, i.e. via a "foreign key" in the same table that points to the `id` value of the parent record.  Thus, the "Parent ID" value for the second row would be 1 to point to the first row.  Also, you should make all values in the `id` row unique as ID values are, by definition, unique.

Comment: Then you could join the table back on itself to get what you need.

Comment: @roryap The problem that I can't modify the schema of the table .

Comment: Then it will be difficult to do what you want.  It looks like a poorly-designed schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking on this you could split data using type prime:

```
select id, value as ValPrime, 'prime' as TypePrime from tbl where type = 'prime'
```

then select :

```
select id, value as ValMonth, type as TypeMonth from tbl where type != 'prime'
```

and then joing them 
but this is workaround, this really not good:)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your schema:

```
id  parentid  value  type
---------------------------
1   null      100    prime
2   1         200    13 month 
3   null      120    prime
4   3         300    13 month
```

and query like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.value AS valuePrime, a.type AS typePrime, b.value AS valueMonth, b.type AS typeMonth
FROM Test AS a
INNER JOIN Test AS b
ON a.id=b.parentid
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work out for you although beware that this would work only in case if there are only 2 records with the same ID as you have shown above.I would still suggest a change in the schema.The following query might help you for the time being.

```
SELECT  q1.id, q1.value AS valueprime, q1.type AS typeprime,q2.value 
as valueMonth,q2.type   as typeMonth
FROM  Test  AS q1 INNER JOIN Test AS q2 ON q1.id = q2.id AND q1.value<> q2.value
```